# R : adding the values in a [row,column] only if value is true in two rows within the same column

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, rows

I am trying to code the following

I have 240 rows and 11 columns. 
I want to do the following:
If the value in (row 1, column 1) was greater than 0 and if the value in (row 1, column 2) was greater than 0, then count the value in (row 1, column 4).

For an example: (row,column)

If (1,1) = (1) AND if (1,2)=(1) then count the value in (1,4)

If (2,1) = (1) AND if (2,2)=(0) then DO NOT COUNT the value in (2,4)

If (3,1) = (0) AND if (3,2)=(1) then DO NOT COUNT the value in (3,4)

etc...

I have already seen a quite similar post, however there was only 1 condition given instead of 2.

I tried the following solution, which did not work
sum(DataFrame_a[DataFrame_a[ ,1] > 0, DataFrame_a[ ,2] > 0, 4])

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output as it is unclear based on the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your only true condition is:

If (1,1) = (1) AND if (1,2)=(1) then count the value in (1,4)

I don't understand count the value

maybe this solution:

```
dplyr::mutate(new=ifelse(col1==1&col2==1,col4,0)
```

gives you a new column
Hope that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Peter Hahn; an ifelse statement should do the trick.

Using dplyr is more elegant. For completeness, here is an example in base:

```
x <- data.frame("X1" = 1:5, "X2" = c(0,1,0,1,1), "X3" = 10:14)
y <- NULL

y <- ifelse(x$X1 > 0 & x$X2 > 0, x$X3,0)

> y
[1]  0 11  0 13 14

> sum(y)
[1] 38
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help.
It works now.

I did the following:

true_sum<-sum(Data[Data[,1]==1 & Data[,2]==1, 4])

that did the trick.

Thx again!